# How can I run my GUI application without desktop enviroment and make it fullscreen?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I run ubuntu 16.04 on Intel Celeron CPU.

Linux kevin-minipc 4.8.0-39-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 15:06:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I run ubuntu 16.04 on Intel Celeron CPU.

Linux kevin-minipc 4.8.0-39-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 15:06:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

and I wrote a Qt appliction. When I run it in desktop environment, it's fullscreen.

Now, I want the system autologin and my application run fullscreen as an X client when system started without desktop environment.

So I made these changes:

```
add a file named lightdm.conf in /etc/lightdm：

[Seat:*]
user-session=myxclient
autologin-user=kevin
autologin-user-timeout=delay
```

kevin is my system account.

add a file myxclient.desktop in /usr/share/xsessions:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=myapp
Comment=myapp
Exec=/home/kevin/myapp
Icon=
Type=Application
```

/home/kevin/myapp is the path to my Qt application.

When I reboot and system have started, myapp will run without desktop, but it IS NOT fullscreen. I tried to run other application in the .desktop file, like firefox, it's not fullscreen either.

So, how can I make it fullscreen? Some other ways are also acceptable. (It's better I don't have to change any configurations when I use the display of different size.)

And another question: Without desktop environment, can I use input program like ibus?

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=75749t

Comment: You need to detect the screen size and move and resize your window to fit (check if a WM is running first).

Comment: @n.m. you reminded me about window manager. I checked and found that in my solution, the window manager 'compiz' doesn't run. So I changed "Exec" in myxclient.desktop into an script, which content is: compiz&；

Comment: If you run with a windiw manager you don't need to do anything. DE is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @n.m. You reminded me about window manager. I checked and found that in my solution, the window manager 'compiz' doesn't run. So I changed "Exec" in myxclient.desktop into an script, which content is: compiz&；/home/kevin/myapp . And it runs fullscreen! I don't know how lightdm starts compiz and whether my way is a good way, but it does work.

Comment: How can I switch ibus input method without desktop?@n.m. Now I can't switch.