# No shadows around window when I start program without desktop environment in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt

OS: Ubuntu 16.04

I wrote a Qt program and run it without desktop environment.

This is my question about how to run it without desktop environment.

[How can I run my GUI application without desktop enviroment and make it fullscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616919/how-can-i-run-my-gui-application-without-desktop-enviroment-and-make-it-fullscre)

Shortly, I do this by two steps:

1. add a lightdm.conf in /etc/lightdm to start my xsession;
2. add a .desktop file in /usr/share/xsession to start my program:

   2.1 start compiz as window manager;

   2.2 start my program.

the last two lines in the script is like:

```
compiz&
/home/kevin/myapp
```

Now I have another **question**.

When a window pops up in my program, there is **no shadow around the window**, just like a program in the desktop environment.

So, there is no clear border between the popped up window and its parent window.

But, when I run it in the desktop environment, there IS shadow around the popped up window.

How can I have shadow around the popped window?

Answer (score 0):

Boiling your question down to its essentials, what you're asking is why, when you run your X11 program without a window manager, you do not get the Window manager's decorations. The answer is, of course, "because there is no window manager".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_window_manager

In a nutshell, X11 windows are just rectangles (usually) that allow an application to draw in exclusive areas, without interfering with other applications. It manages input like you're used to, but visually, it's just rectangles.

X11 does allow a special program to run, referred to as a Window Manager. This program gets to know whenever you want to display a window, and gets to do stuff to that window. In particular, the standard thing to do is to wrap your window inside the window manager's window, and display a bunch of controls for your window. These include maximize, minimize, close, an easy way to move the window around, resize etc.

You can see this extra window by using a program called `xwininfo`. You will see that, when you run your program without a manger, it's just your window. When you run it with a manager, your window is a child for one or more (depending on the WM) other windows.

The shadow you talk about is also something that your window manager does. If you run without it, you will not get it.

As for solutions, I can think of two:

1. Write your own mini-window manager. This can either be an official window manager, or just wrap your own application window with a bigger window that adds one pixel of black border.

or

2. Use a window manager, and ask it not to add its controls to your window. Precise details vary slightly between window managers, but the [DOCK](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#idm140238712332688) window type might do what you want.

Comment: I started compiz. Compiz cannot do this? If compiz not started, my program can not even run to show its UI.

Comment: maybe I should to start a window decorator or choose a theme for compiz?But how?